# Displaying all but [0] element of map key arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, key-value

The premise of this question is that in the following TS block, I am creating an array that is made from the given map's keys and console logging to ensure that the arrays are created as needed.

```
  public certKeys: String[];
  public certMap: Map<String, DataObject[]> = new Map();
  public allData: DataObject[];

  @Input()
  set data(data: DataObject[]) {
    if (!data) { return; }
    new Set(data.map(i => i.certTypeDescription)).forEach(i => {
      this.certMap.set(i, []);
    });

    data.forEach(i => {
      this.certMap.get(i.certTypeDescription).push(i);
    });

    this.certKeys = Array.from(this.certMap.keys());
    this.allData = data;

    console.log(this.certMap);
  }
```

Now when this translates to the HTML portion of this, I am wanting to display the most recent record (or the [0] element) of each key array. This is already being accomplished. However, the other portion is that in the accordion drop down, I need to retrieve the rest of the elements save for the [0] element. below you will see what I have so far:

```
<app-basic-card myTitle="Data">
  <i cardIcon class="uxd uxd-mode-edit uxd-lg uxd-pointer text-primary" (click)="openEditDialog()"></i>
  <div cardBody class="accordion" *ngIf="allData; else loading">
    <p *ngIf="allData?.length === 0">
      No allData found...
    </p>
    <mat-accordion *ngIf="allData?.length>0">
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let cert of certKeys">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <ng-container>
              <div>
                <div class="w-50 float-left">{{cert}}</div>
                <div class="w-50 float-right">
                  <i class="uxd uxd-lg" [ngClass]="getCertIcon(certMap.get(cert)[0]?.certificationResult)"></i>&nbsp;
                  {{getDateTaken(certMap.get(cert)[0].certificationDate)}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-container>
          <div *ngFor = "let certKeys of allData">
            <div class="w-50 float-left">{{cert}}</div>
            <div class="w-50 float-right">
              <i class="uxd uxd-lg" [ngClass]="getCertIcon(certMap.get(cert).certificationResult)"></i>&nbsp;
              {{getDateTaken(certMap.get(cert).certDate)}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </div>
  <ng-template cardLoading #loading class="text-center">
    <mat-spinner class="loading-spinner" style="margin:0 auto;" diameter="50"></mat-spinner>
  </ng-template>
</app-basic-card>
```

My question is how do I accomplish retrieving every element but the [0] element of each key array? There is something that I very obviously am missing. I would appreciate any answers that are given and resources that may point me in the right direction. I thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Angular tbh, but if you can modify the array you could use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method, which returns a shallow copy of the original array, so the original will stay untouched.

---

Can you change this line:

`<div *ngFor = "let certKeys of allData">`

Into this:

`<div *ngFor = "let certKeys of allData.slice(1)">`

?

---

Working snippet of the `slice()` function.

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const itemsWithoutTheFirstItem = items.slice(1);

// Target array contains all but first item
console.log(itemsWithoutTheFirstItem);

// Original array stays the same
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Unfortunately upon trying that, it doesn't work. I even thought to try ng-repeat and index, but I believe the problem is that it is only looking at how many arrays there are, rather than try to display all the values inside of each array.

Comment: What about creating a function inside the Component that would return all but the N items? Something like
`getCertKeys(startingIndex) { return this.certKeys.slice(startingIndex) };`? And you can then call it with `this.getCertKeys(1);`.

Comment: what kind of variable would startingIndex represent?

Comment: It would define the number of elements you want to remove from the beginning. You don't have to do that, but it is more generic than creating `getAllButFirstCertKeys()`. When I think about it, it would make sense to name it `getCertKeysFromIndex(startingIndex)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think of two options right now. The first one is using `*ngIf` or a simple Pipe.

*First option:*

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let cert of certKeys; let index = index">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header *ngIf="index > 0">
    ...
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

*Second option:*

Create a Angular Pipe, which returns a new array except the first entry:

```
@Pipe({name: 'ignoreFirst'})
export class IgnoreFirstEntryPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(arr: any[]) {
        // Returns a new array without the original first entry
        return arr.slice(1); 
    }

}
```

And in your html:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let cert of certKeys | ignoreFirst">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    ...
</mat-expansion-panel>
```